# How to Implement Dynamic Routing from Database in CodeIgniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

As I have mentioned, may you please help me to implement dynamic routing from the database in CodeIgniter 4 ? I have implemented a blog where all blog posts store in the **posts** table. The table has the **slug** column which is used to fetch a blog.

Site pages will be look like:

[www.mysite.com/how-to-work-with-ci](http://www.mysite.com/how-to-work-with-ci)

[www.mysite.com/your-health-your-wealth](http://www.mysite.com/your-health-your-wealth)

As, we have already implemented such features in Codeigniter 3, but I did not found anything equivalent in CI4.

Please help me regarding this. Please let me know if you want any other info regarding this from me, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

It's actually quite easy. First, you will need to configure the routes as follow in routes files :

```
$routes->get('blogs/(:any)', 'BlogController::show/$1');
```

Here (:any) is a placeholder (slug) for the dynamic route which will be passed to your controller.

In your BlogController, you will need to fetch the value passed to this parameter.

```
show($slug){
... switch($slug)
}
```

You can also refer to the following for better of the routes in CI4.

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/routing.html

Comment: Thank u for answering.  I want to use URL structure without /blog segment, i.e. www.mysite.com/your-health-your-wealth,   and "/your-health-your-wealth" will also be dynamic.  So, how will I achieve this ?

Comment: Although I have not tested it. You should be able to do so by simply just using '(:any)'

Comment: (:any) is definitely a good solution, but if there is other segments such as, /admin,   /category, then by using (:any) made these pages redirect to that BlogController which is inappropriate.

Comment: Yes you can do that as well. You can group the routes and use regex as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
// app\Config\Routes.php

$routes->get('/', 'Home::index');
$routes->addPlaceholder('admin', 'admin');
$routes->addPlaceholder('pub', '[a-z]+');

$routes->get('(:admin)', 'Home::$1');
$routes->get('(:admin)/(:any)', 'Home::$1/$2'); // remember $1 = admin

$routes->get('(:pub)', 'Home::index/$1'); // you can use (:any)
```

```php
// app\Controllers\Home.php

<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Home extends BaseController
{
    public function index($slug = 'home')
    {
        echo 'INDEX: ' . $slug;
    }

    public function admin($page = 'main admin')
    {
        echo 'ADMIN: ' . $page;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
//app\Config\Routes.php
namespace Config;
$this->db = \Config\Database::connect();
$query= $this->db->table($table); // routes table or slug name table
$query->select($field); 
$res = $query->get();
$result= $res->getResultArray();
foreach( $result as $row){
  $route->get[$row['slug_name']]                = $row['controller_name'];
  $route->get[$row['slug_name'].'/:any' ]       =$row['controller_name'];
}
```